# How to read data from a .dat file and store them in another file

Tags: python-2.7

I want to know how to split data of a massive file having many columns of data. The data are separated by gap. I am using them in my code and storing them in another file in columns wise. Using below code I can store only one column in one file but I want to store all 4 columns in the same file with gap. How can I do it?

```
 from itertools import izip
 u,v,w,p = izip(*(map(int,line.split()) for line in open('data.dat')))
 print("u is", list(u))
 print("v is", list(v))
 print("w is", list(w))
 print("p is", list(p))
 thefile = open('test.txt', 'w')
 for item in list(u):
    thefile.write("%f\n" % item)
```

Comment: Please show us a few sample input lines and the output you expect. It's not easy to make out from your description what you are trying to do.

Comment: My input is like this:100 200 300 400
                               101 201 301 401
                               102 202 302 402              and i also want my output like this 100 200 300 400
             101 201 301 401
             102 202 302 402      in another file. Sorry it is not formatted properly

Comment: Actually 100,101,102 in on column similarly other 200, 300,400 in different columns. I want to save them in different file in similar fashion

Comment: @SatinathDebnath - edit your question and put your source data as well as the expected outcome in the question itself.